# GWT 100% height panel with scroll

Tags: gwt

Could anyone help me make normal layout in GWT.

I need a main panel which:

1. fills all the browser space (100% height);
2. if being collapsed too much shows scroll bars (autoscroll).

When I use old layout (RootPanel, VerticalPanel) I have scroll, but can't get 100% height.

When I use new layout (RootLayoutPanel, DockLayoutPanel) I get 100% height, but I don't get any scroll. And also I have some troubles in IE.

Is there any sample showing how to achieve both goals?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've got this as a RootLayoutPanel with a DockLayoutPanel inside. In the center is a ScrollPanel that takes up the rest of the space and provides the scrolling if needed. My .ui.xml (UIBinder stuff) looks kind of like this:

```
<g:DockLayoutPanel unit="PX" ui:field="Dock">
            <!-- the g: north, west, east, south guys go here -->
    <g:center>
    <g:ScrollPanel addStyleNames='{style.document_area}'>
    </g:ScrollPanel>
    </g:center>
</g:DockLayoutPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would try :

1. Your first panel (except the root)
   is a ScrollPanel
2. Your second panel would be your
   LayoutPanel (or DockLayoutPanel if
   you prefer).

Comment: this won't work: if you place a LayoutPanel in a ScrollPanel odd things will happen: For example placing a DockLayoutPanel in any "not-layout-panel" only "north" will be shown.